# Simplify multiple mkdir and symlink in a loop bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm performing the following operations

```
# Mount cache directories

mkdir -p $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.gradle
rm -rf ~/.gradle
ln -sf $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.gradle ~/

mkdir -p $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.m2
rm -rf ~/.m2
ln -sf $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.m2 ~/

mkdir -p $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.mvn
rm -rf ~/.mvn
ln -sf $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.mvn ~/

mkdir -p $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.sbt
rm -rf ~/.sbt
ln -sf $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.sbt ~/

mkdir -p $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.ivy2
rm -rf ~/.ivy2
ln -sf $SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/.ivy2 ~/
```

Now I'd like to reformat this into a simplified way where i can just mention the directories in an array, like `['.m2', '.mvn', '.gradle']` and one single loop that performs the same operations. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

A simple shell loop:

```
for subdir in .gradle .m2 .mvn .sbt .ivy2; do
    mkdir -p "$SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/$subdir"
    rm -rf "$HOME/$subdir"
    ln -s "$SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/$subdir" "$HOME"
done
```

If you want to use a separate array in `bash` for example:

```
dirs=( .gradle .m2 .mvn .sbt .ivy2 )

for subdir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    mkdir -p "$SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/$subdir"
    rm -rf "$HOME/$subdir"
    ln -s "$SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/$subdir" "$HOME"
done
```

Or, for `/bin/sh`:

```
set -- .gradle .m2 .mvn .sbt .ivy2

for subdir do
    mkdir -p "$SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/$subdir"
    rm -rf "$HOME/$subdir"
    ln -s "$SHARED_VOL/track/$TRACK/$subdir" "$HOME"
done
```

For extra safety, you may want `set -u` and/or `set -e` before running these loops. `set -e` would terminate the script if an error occurs, and `set -u` would treat a the expansion of an unset variable as an error (for catching any misspelt variable names, for example).